# Dart Mqtt5 library throws InvalidHeaderException when publishing a message

Tags: dart, mqtt

I am trying to build a flutter UI app to publish and subscribe messages over mqtt5 protocol. I am using the library `mqtt5_client: ^3.3.4`
Subscription works like a charm. But while publishing the library throws InvalidHeaderException. The source code is not of much help in resolving the problem.
Thanks in advance for any pointer.

The full code and exception stack trace is given below. Problem is in the publish method in the call to publish

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:mqtt5_client/mqtt5_client.dart';
import 'package:mqtt5_client/mqtt5_server_client.dart';


class MQTTClient {
  late MqttServerClient _client;

  MQTTClient(String url, String clientId, int port) {
    _client = MqttServerClient(url, clientId);
    _client.port = port;
    _client.keepAlivePeriod = 60;
    _client.onConnected = onConnected;
    _client.onDisconnected = onDisconnected;
    MqttConnectMessage connectMessage =
        MqttConnectMessage().withWillQos(MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    _client.connectionMessage = connectMessage;
     _client.logging(on: true);
  }

  void subscribe(String topic) {
    _client.onSubscribed = onSubscribed;
    _client.subscribe(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce);
    _client.updates.listen((List<MqttReceivedMessage<MqttMessage?>>? msg) {
      final recMess = msg![0].payload as MqttPublishMessage;
      List<int> msgbytes = (recMess.payload.message)!.cast<int>();
      print(
          'Received message: topic is ${msg[0].topic}, payload is ${utf8.decode(msgbytes)} ');
    });
  }

  void publish(String topic, String message) {
    final builder = MqttPayloadBuilder();
    builder.addString(message);
    _client.publishMessage(topic, MqttQos.atLeastOnce, builder.payload!);
    _client.published!.listen((event) {
      print(
          'Published topic: topic is ${event.variableHeader!.topicName}, with Qos ${event.header!.qos}');
    });
  }

  Future<int> connect() async {
    try {
      await _client.connect();
    } on MqttNoConnectionException catch (e) {
      print('connect exception - $e');
    } on SocketException catch (e) {
      print('socket exception - $e');
    }
    if (_client.connectionStatus!.state == MqttConnectionState.connected) {
      print('client connected');
    } else {
      print(
          'client connection failed - disconnecting, status is ${_client.connectionStatus}');
      _client.disconnect();
      exit(-1);
    }

    return 0;
  }
}

MqttSubscription onSubscribed(MqttSubscription subscription) {
  print('subscribed $subscription');
  return subscription;
}

void onConnected() {
  print("client connected");
}

void onDisconnected() {
  print('client disconnected');
}
```

The exception stacktrace is :

```
Unhandled exception:
mqtt-client::InvalidHeaderException: The supplied header is invalid. Header must be at least 2 bytes long.
#0      MqttHeader.readFrom (package:mqtt5_client/src/messages/mqtt_header.dart:69:7)
#1      new MqttHeader.fromByteBuffer (package:mqtt5_client/src/messages/mqtt_header.dart:19:5)
#2      MqttByteBuffer.isMessageAvailable (package:mqtt5_client/src/utility/mqtt_byte_buffer.dart:66:29)
#3      MqttServerConnection._onData (package:mqtt5_client/src/connectionhandling/server/mqtt_server_connection.dart:60:26)
#4      _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1586:10)
#5      _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#6      _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#7      _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)
#8      _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648:7)
#9      _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)
#10     _Socket._onData (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:2324:41)
#11     _RootZone.runUnaryGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:1586:10)
#12     _BufferingStreamSubscription._sendData (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:339:11)
#13     _BufferingStreamSubscription._add (dart:async/stream_impl.dart:271:7)
#14     _SyncStreamControllerDispatch._sendData (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:774:19)
#15     _StreamController._add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:648:7)
#16     _StreamController.add (dart:async/stream_controller.dart:596:5)
#17     new _RawSocket.<anonymous closure> (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1849:33)
#18     _NativeSocket.issueReadEvent.issue (dart:io-patch/socket_patch.dart:1322:14)
#19     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:40:21)
#20     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:49:5)
#21     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:122:13)
#22     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:193:5)
```

Comment: I don't see where in your code you are actually calling `publish()`? Also that error appears to be handling a message from the broker, so without a network capture to see what type of incoming message it's processing it will be hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: A [similar issue](https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt5_client/issues/41#issue-1526216738) has been raised in the github repo.

Comment: I haven't included the code that calls the publish method. It is a simple call  
 MQTTClient client = MQTTClient('broker.emqx.io', 'NodeMCU8266', '1883');
  await client. Connect();
  client. Publish("led/state", "OFF");  I raised the issue on github too. I also received a resolution. Here it is : https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/issues/438#issuecomment-1378346434

Answer (score 0):

The author of this library has resolved the issue; The error is specific to mqtt5 and is under investigation. The solution is to handle|ignore the exception as this occurs after the message is published. Another option is to use mqtt_client instead of mqtt5_client. Both methods work https://github.com/shamblett/mqtt_client/issues/438#issuecomment-1378346434